# What noun is の standing in for here?

Tags: grammar

Listening to podcast about traveling, and host brings up benefits of travel such as:

どういう生活をしていたのか**っていうの**を見ることができました

“I was able to see what kind of life they were living”.

What does the というの add here? You don’t need it of course, but what might this の pronoun be subbing in for? Since it was framed as a question I first assumed it meant “question”, but that turns into something like:

“I was able to see the question: “What kind of life they were living?””

…which doesn’t make sense. Does it just mean “thing”? And if so, what nuance might it add to the sentence?

Comment: I don't think "question" is that bad. It only doesn't go too well with the verb "to see." How about "(answer to) the question?"

Answer (score 3):

の is not standing in for any noun.  It's not a pronoun.  It is *nominalizing* that which precedes it which isn't already a noun.  That means, it's making the sentence:

> どういう生活をしていたのかっていう

into a noun.  That way there is a noun to attach を見る to.

っていう is just an informal way of saying という.  It's also a not uncommon way to set up a relative clause in Japanese.

So, we have two ideas in this sentence that we want to link up:

- どういう生活をしていたのか
- *noun*を見ることができました

in English,

- What kind of a life is was he living?
- I was able to see it.

In English, we can just embed the first sentence and treat it like something that can be seen.

> I was able to see *what kind of a life he was living*

But in Japanese, we should *nominalize* the embedded question.

> どういう生活をしていたのかというの

There is no easy way to express what Japanese is doing in a direct translation without getting very clunky and losing the thread of the idea.  But in Japanese, というの is nearly invisible glue.  It just serves a very simple purpose.  And it allows us to link the two ideas as we did in English.

Voila!

> どういう生活をしていたのかというのを見ることができました

Comment: If it’s the nominalizer, with the sentence being an embedded question, doesn’t it work without the というの?  And if it does, why might you use というの glue in addition? Does it add more emphasis?

Comment: という really doesn't add any nuance.  It's often used whether it is needed or not, much like filler phrases.

Comment: I don't believe you can just say, どういう生活をしていたのかの.  So, in this case, you do need という.  You could say, どういう生活をしていたのを見た.  But then it's perhaps a matter of style.  Or the speaker is responding directly to a question and is thus quoting the question.

Comment: I was more thinking: どういう生活をしていたのかを見た。But if it’s often superfluous glue that makes sense

Comment: って itself often gets used much like は to mark a topic.  That's not what's happening here.  It's a separate topic that I am not skilled enough to answer.

Comment: You can say どういう生活をしていたのか（を）見ることができた.

Comment: @aguijonazo I've been mulling this over since I wrote that comment.  Thank you for your response.